# Download or link to a font - benefit?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Basic question, I know I can either Download or link to a font, for example google fonts. Is there a benefit between choosing to link or download the font?

I am creating a web application with a few short paragraphs in RoR, but it's just a general question.

Comment: There's whole slew of pros and cons for all the various ways of adding web fonts to a project, however without some details around what you need and for what kind of project, it's hard to answer. All anyone could answer with any certaintly is "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit I can imagine, is having a guarantee that your font will always be available if you download it and store it in your project directory. Whereas, if you link to a font there is a (rather low) possibility that the link will break in the future or something along those lines.